# JS [ES5] How to assign objects with setters and getters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
obj1 = Object.create({}, { property: { enumerable: true, value: 42 } })

> obj1.property = 56
> 56
> obj1.property
> 42
```

with **use strict** there is an error.

I want to combine multiple objects:
with jQuery.extend():

```
new_obj = $.extend(true, objN, obj1)
```

with ES6 Object.assign:

```
new_obj = Object.assign({}, objN, obj1)
```

In any case, the getter turns into a regular property, and therefore it can be changed. How to avoid it?

Comment: There are no setters and getters in your example, you've just got a non-writable property?

Comment: Yes, it simple example. But with setter and getter same.

Comment: Was your question related to fixing the error when using the 'use strict' directive? If so, change your variable assignment to use a keyword such as `var` or `let`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function that also copies over property attributes:

```
function extend(target, ...sources) {
    for (let source of sources)
        for (let key of Object.keys(source))
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key));
    return target;
}
```

But notice there is good reason why `Object.assign` does not, it could have weird effects if getters and setters are closures.

Comment: Does not work with property in _proto_.
$.extend better

Comment: There were no properties in the prototype of your example object. If you want to copy all of those as well, iterate the prototype chains of your sources as well. Btw, `Object.assign` doesn't take into account inherited properties either.

Comment: Should replace `for (let key of Object.keys(source))` with `for (const key in source)` and add a check for `if (source != null)` to avoid bugs and  to comply with the standard `assign` method. Other than that +1