# Getter function evaluated when using object assign

Tags: javascript, merge, ecmascript-6

I was experimenting in the console and I ran into something that perplexed me:

```
var foo = {
   bar: 10,
   get baz() {return this.bar}
}
console.log(foo.baz) // 10
var fubar = Object.assign({}, foo);
console.log(fubar); // {bar: 10, baz: 10}
```

What I don't understand here is why `baz` is `10` when it is under `fubar`, instead of a `getter` like it was in `foo`. Thank you for your time in explaining.

Comment: Well `Object.assign()` only copies *enumerable* properties... (You may also want to check what `Object.keys(foo)` returns...)

Comment: That’s just how `Object.assign` works. It works like looping through the enumerable properties and assigning them to the other object.

Comment: Thank you for the responses - is there anyway to copy a getter?

Comment: @nnnnnn But `baz` _is enumerable_ and it is also copied, just not as a getter.

Comment: @Xufox - Yes, exactly. `foo.baz` evaluates to whatever value the getter returns. That's how you'd normally want it to work when enumerating properties, isn't it? (So that it would work in `for..in` loops, etc.) MDN says that `Object.assign()` "uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters."

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to assign objects with setters and getters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37054596/1048572)